# Find the next terms in this sequence. 4,82,1

Tags: number-sequence, no-computers

Find the next few terms X, X, X. in this sequence
Give your reasoning

4, 82, 1, 14, 84, 88, 0, 82, 81, 22, 12, X, X, X

Comment: Is there any special significance to the first three terms being included in the title? It seems that between that and and asking for the last three terms that you're implying the sequence involves triplets? Seems like a trick or red herring..

Comment: @Carley.   No significance..just gave few terms.  developed  the sequence based on widely used system for........I just gave enough terms to get the flavor of the series....you can continue the series forever..no significance in just putting 3 X s.